# Iframe with embed Youtube Video stops after alert shows up?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, ionic2

I have the problem that my embed Youtube Video stops playing after a Popup like alerts or ion-select get called.

This is the html:

```
<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/aasdfsdf?showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&playsinline=1' frameborder="0" width="300" height="150" allowfullscreen no-padding webkit-playsinline playsinline></iframe>
```

I really cant show more code because there isnt more. Only a Button below the iframe witch pop up a alert. And if i do that the video stops and get load a second time.

How could i slove this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TRY THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alfinpaul/yy0au20q/1/)

**But its applicable on embeded youtube video**

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<script>

    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
            alert('completed');
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Well this is the best solution at the moment. Thank you

Comment: happy to help you.